# CSS3 negative margin issue

Tags: css

I know that my question was addressed many time on this site. However, I can't seem to find my answer. I'm trying to create a sticky footer on my pages.My pages are divided in 3 div.

- top
- middle
- bottom

I've created a layout.css file. Here it is:

```
html,body { 
  margin: 0; 
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
  font-size: 14px; 
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
}

#pageTop {
  height: 90px;
}

#pageMiddle {

  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

#pageMiddle:after {
  content: "";
  display: block; 
}
#pageBottom, #pageMiddle:after {
  height: 50px; 
}
```

I don't understand how to remove the pageTop height from the pageMiddle min-height. This seems to be the issue.

Thanks for your help on this matter.

Comment: I really can't understand your issue.

Comment: Me neither. Can you recreate your situation on jsFiddle or similar?

Comment: You will need jquery for this, you have to create a variable for pageTop and use 90px as value, then set the css height for the middle one as pageMiddle - pageTop and add the new resulted variable as inline height css for pageMiddle

Comment: Can you use percentage heights instead? Set `#PageTop` to 10% and then your `#pageMiddle` would become 90%

Comment: having 'margin-bottom:-50px' will move your `#pageMiddle` down the page. I think you want to move it up so it is not overlapped by the footer right? In that case, either `margin-top:-50px;' or `margin-bottom:50px;` should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all and thanks for giving me some pointers. After a few days, I finally got the answer.

Like mentioned above, I had 3 div:

- top
- middle
- bottom

I was trying to apply a sticky footer on my bottom div. without any success.

Here is how I managed to solve this issue.

I inserted the top and middle div in a wrapper div. Having only 2 main divs on my page.
It looks like this now.

- Wrapper

  - top
  - Middle
- bottom

here is the css:

```
#wrapper{
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}
#top {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 90px;
}

#middle {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: block; 
}
#bottom, #wrapper:after {
    width:1000px;
    height: 50px; 
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Here is my html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>My title</title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top">Header</div>
    <div id="middle">Content</div>
<div id="bottom">Footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is very simple but it works.

Again thanks for your replies.